# Expand variables on ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am working with ansible and I am using some variables from an inventory, grabbing it like this:

inventory.yml

```
node1:
  myvar: {{ value | default('') }}
```

Doing it like this is catching the variable if it exists - ok for me. If it doesn't exist it's catching a blank space.
Now I am using this var so I'd like it to use the var myvar if it exists but if it doesn't exist I should not use it.
How can I change the code in inventory file for this effect?

I searched and found out the omit statement in ansible. I tried it:

```
{{ myvar| default(omit) }}
```

So I was expecting that when myvar doesn't exist, it would not expand it at all. But instead it is expandid it into something like:
"__omit_place_holder__fff04c27ce985720dfc585a846df639af101f0e4".

Comment: In what context are you using this variable? In a template? As an argument to a task? Please update your question to include a [mcve] so that we can see the exact behavior you're asking about.

Comment: I am using in a template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a variable in template, the `omit` filter won't do you any good. That's only useful in arguments to tasks; e.g:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - copy:
        src: "{{ data.src|default(omit) }}"
        content: "{{ data.content|default(omit) }}"
        dest: output.txt
      vars:
        data:
          content: "this is a test"
```

Defining both `src` and `content` is an invalid configuration, but because we're using `omit` here, the task will only see one or the other depending on what keys are set on `data`.

---

For what you're doing, the solution you've proposed -- `{{ myvar|default('') }}` --- seems simplest; that't won't result in "a blank space" when `myvar` is undefined; it will result in the empty string. That is, if your template looks like:

```
one-two{{myvar|default('')}}-three
```

And `myvar` is undefined, the output will be:

```
one-two-three
```

You can of course also use an `if` statement if the above solution is insufficiently flexible:

```
{% if myvar is defined %}
myvar: {{ myvar }}
{% endif %}
```